# FMDatabase: reflect data on TableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have been making such App.
[BooksViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlSrL.png)
↑↓
[EditViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOkJP.png)

SQL:`books (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, author TEXT, title TEXT, copyright TEXT, category TEXT)`
I customized the TableViewCell with xib.
cell.label1.text = book.title;
    cell.label2.text = book.copyright;
    cell.label3.text = book.category;
But the data are not reflect on TableViewCell.

I have this code.
BooksViewController

```
    #import "BooksCell.h"
    //////
            - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        static NSString* CellIdentifier = @"BooksCell";

        BooksCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if( cell == nil )
        {
            cell = [[[BooksCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        }

        Book* book = [self bookAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.label1.text = book.title;
        cell.label2.text = book.copyright;
        cell.label3.text = book.category;

        return cell;
    }
```

EditViewController

```
- (IBAction)saveData:(id)sender
{    
    Book* newBook = [[Book alloc] init];
    newBook.bookId    = self.book.bookId;
    newBook.title     = _titleTextField.text;
    newBook.author    = _authorTextField.text;
    newBook.copyright    = _copyrightTextField.text;
    newBook.category    = _categoryTextField.text;

    if( self.book )
    {
        [self.delegate editBookDidFinish:self.book newBook:newBook];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.delegate addBookDidFinish:newBook];
    }
}
```

BooksCell.h

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BooksCell : UITableViewCell{
    UILabel* label1;
    UILabel* label2;
    UILabel* label3;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel* label1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel* label2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel* label3;

@end
```

The cell is blank.
But when I describe

```
cell.textLabel.text = book.title;
```

in the method [cellForRowAtIndexPath],title is displayed at the cell correctly.
Any idea on how I could fix it?

Comment: Where is this method [self bookAtIndexPath:indexPath] is declared and also check using break Point that is this method is returning some thing or not ??

Comment: Put some NSLogs in your code.

Comment: - (Book*)bookAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
 NSArray* booksByAuthor = [self.books objectForKey:[self.authors objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
 return [booksByAuthor objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
in BooksViewController.m   there is not breakpoint.Thank you for comment.